# Data Views not working in Entity Framework after updating MySQL.Data

Tags: entity-framework, mysql-connector

We finally got a chance to update MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.EntityFramework in our .NET project from 8.0.19 to 8.0.33, as well as the MySQL and MySQL .NET Connector installed.
Immediately, all data views have this issue, when accessed it throws:

```
Table 'db_name.db_name.view_name' doesn't exist
```

Downgrading everything back to 8.0.19 causes it to correctly use 'db_name.view_name'.

I don't want to stay on an archaic MySQL version but I can't justify to management spending countless hours going down a MySQL rabbit hole for this. Has anyone else run into this?